# AS3 Flash calling main timeline from within a movieclip within a movie clip

Tags: actionscript-3, navigation, timeline

I've looked through similar question on this site and can't find a solution, so here is my problem:

I have a save function that saves some data.This function is in 1 movie clip in another movie clip. After the save I want to gotoAndStop(1) of the main time line not the current nested one...can anybody help?

Below is the code:

```
function save()
{

    var oldname:String = so.data.username;
    so.data.username = oldname + tf.text + " " + nf.text + "\n";
    tf.text = "";
    nf.text = ""; // resets textfields
    so.flush(); // writes changes to disk
    trace("Saved");
    gotoAndStop(1);  <<----this must goto frame 1 of the main time line??
}
```

This is AS3. In AS2 I used to be able to call _root. or _parent. and that would work fine but now it throws a compiler error. Stage.gotoAndStop(1); also doesnt work...

Appreciate any help,
Thanks in advance
Luben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the topmost `DisplayObject` using [`root`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#root). Because `DisplayObject` does not have a `gotoAndStop()` method, attempting `root.gotoAndStop()` will result in:

> 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndStop through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.

You can however [typecast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660275/as3-casting-one-type-to-another) `root` to `MovieClip`<sup>1</sup>, which will grant access to it:

```
MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(1); // or:
(root as MovieClip).gotoAndStop(1);
```

Typecasting to `MovieClip` will also allow you to access user-defined properties and functions on the main timeline - this is because MovieClips are [`dynamic`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f89.html) which drops compile-time constraints on what properties and methods you are allowed to access on an object.

---

<sup>1</sup>Except for in cases where you have a document class that inherits `Sprite` instead of `MovieClip`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't do a lot of coding on the Flash Timeline (and I suggest that you start looking into using external class definitions via the Document Root if your application is even of medium complexity); but the following suggest should still hold true.

In AS3, Events dispatched on the Display List can have their `bubbles` property set to true which will enable event bubbling.  By enabling event bubbling you can listen for the even higher up on the display list, [the following article](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/eventbubbles-eventcancelable-and-eventcurrenttarget) does a great job of explaining it with a demo you can play with.

In your application let's assume you have two "chunks" of actions, the `save` function definition and the `main` function definition:

**Main**

```
// Add an event listener, when we hear a 'SaveEvent' we will call
// the onSaveEvent function.
addEventListener("SaveEvent", onSaveEvent);

// This function is called when we hear a 'SaveEvent'.
function onSaveEvent(event : Event) : void {
    trace("Main heard event: " + event.type);

    // We can now instruct our Main Timeline.
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

**Save**

```
// Perform your save operation as before...
so.flush(); // writes changes to disk
trace("Saved");

// Now dispatch an Event, make sure we set it to bubble.
var bubbles : Boolean = true;
dispatchEvent(new Event("SaveEvent", bubbles));
```

Answer (score 0):

//Hence you can go to the first frame of your Scene 1

```
MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 1");
```