# AS3 Casting one type to another

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a base class called `Room` and a subclass called `Attic`, and another called `Basement`.

I have a controller class that has an attribute called `CurrentLocation` which is type `Room`.  The idea is I want to be able to put `Attic` or `Basement` in that property and get it back, then cast that to whatever type it is.

So if on the controller the content is of type `Attic`, I'm trying to figure out how to explicitly cast it.  I thought I knew but its not working...  Here's what I thought it would be, borrowing from Java:

```
var myAttic:Attic = (Attic) Controller.CurrentLocation;
```

This gives me a syntax error:

> 1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before instance.

So how do you cast implicitly?  Or can you?  I could swear I've done this before as as3.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here are your options for casting in ActionScript 3:

1. Use [`as`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#as).

   ```
   var myAttic:Attic = Controller.CurrentLocation as Attic; // Assignment.
   (Controller.CurrentLocation as Attic).propertyOrMethod(); // In-line use.
   ```

   This will assign `null` to `myAttic` if the cast fails.
2. Wrap in `Type()`.

   ```
   var myAttic:Attic = Attic(Controller.CurrentLocation); // Assignment.
   Attic(Controller.CurrentLocation).propertyOrMethod(); // In-line use.
   ```

   This throws a [`TypeError`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/TypeError.html) if the cast fails.

Comment: Why is that prefered? It depends. Also `Class(bla)` is orders of magnitude slower if it fails. Checking for `null` is always easier.

Comment: @Marty Wallace so tell us how do "prefer" to wrap in Array, XML or Object?

Comment: @Marty Wallace imagine we have Array or XML or Object type instead of Attic. Will that affect your answer?

Comment: @Marty Wallace no you don't get it... var foo:* = []; var typedFoo:Array = ??? how would you make your preferred wrap here?

Comment: That's exactly a reminder that **casting** in AS3 should be done via "as" for any possible type. Functional style is **type conversation** (that could be useful for primitive types). Period.