# Access child class property in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class

I cant access a property of a child object of a class. I get this error when i try to trace it:

> Access of possibly undefined property tipo through a reference with
>   static type flash.display:DisplayObject.

My code is the following:

**Class**

```
public class naftaBonusClass extends MovieClip {
    private var _tipo = "nafta";

    public function get tipo():String
    {
        return _tipo;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
if (getChildAt(i).localToGlobal(new Point(stage.y,0)).y > 650){
    trace(getChildAt(i).tipo);
    removeChildAt(i);
}
```

And another question that i have is in this same way if i can know the class of the child because i want to manage various different classes and know what class is each child. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to cast the result of `.getChildAt()` to your `naftaBonusClass` object first:

```
if(getChildAt(i).localToGlobal(new Point(stage.y, 0)).y > 650)
{
    var myObj:naftaBonusClass = getChildAt(i) as naftaBonusClass;
    trace(myObj.tipo);

    removeChildAt(i);
}
```

Or simply:

```
trace((getChildAt(i) as naftaBonusClass).tipo);
```

[Here's some more information about type casting in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660275/as3-casting-one-type-to-another/9660323#9660323).

As for not knowing what each object will be, that's something that you need to clean up and manage properly. For example, you could store each element in an Array and each of those Arrays should contains a certain type of object. You'll then be able to look over the Array with a typed `for each()` loop:

```
for each(var i:naftaBonusClass in naftaList)
{
    trace(i.tipo);
}
```

Going even further, you could create a base class for your objects and store a method in there which will be called in your loop. That way you just need to cast to the base class and call that method, which can be overridden in your subclasses:

```
class MyChild extends MovieClip
{
    public function update():void{ }
}
```

Then your modified `naftaBonusClass`:

```
class naftaBonusClass extends MyChild
{
    private var _tipo:String = "nafta";

    // This is where the work should be done.
    override public function update():void
    {
        trace(tipo);
    }

    public function get tipo():String
    {
        return _tipo;
    }
}
```

And your updated loop:

```
if(getChildAt(i).localToGlobal(new Point(stage.y, 0)).y > 650)
{
    (getChildAt(i) as MyClass).update();
    removeChildAt(i);
}
```

Comment: The thing is that i dont know the class because my childs can be of various different classes.

Comment: But they all have the property "tipo".

Comment: @JonathanCalb Create a base class that *all of your objects* will inherit from with the property `tipo` defined. If you need to do different things with each element, you should create a base class with an `update()` method which all of your objects will extend, and then do whatever you need to do in each of the subclasses.

Comment: I cant dynamically know the class of the child and trace it? That could be a solution too. But i dont know how to do that even. If its possible..

Comment: @JonathanCalb You should move the tasks into the objects themselves rather than spending time and resources trying to determine what objects are at the outer level of the application and then manipulating them from there. I've updated my answer to try show that as simply as I could.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to typecast that instance unless you want it to be treated as a display object:

```
if (getChildAt(i).localToGlobal(new Point(stage.y,0)).y > 650) {
    trace(naftaBonusClass(getChildAt(i)).tipo);
    removeChildAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What Marty is telling you is the best way to accomplish what you want.  But if you have no way of knowing or controlling the classes of the objects, then you can always down-cast them and access tipo like this:

```
if (getChildAt(i).localToGlobal(new Point(stage.y,0)).y > 650){
    var theObject:Object = getChildAt(i) as Object;
    if(theObject.hasOwnProperty("tipo")){
        trace(theObject.tipo);
    }
    removeChildAt(i);
}
```