# How do one cast a instance of subclass to its superclass?

Tags: actionscript-3, types, subclass, superclass, coercion

So I have this superclass grid class, and a subclass of the grid class named GrassTile1, GrassTile2, etc... all of the instance of the subclasses are stored in an array. How am I suppose to convert the instance of subclass to its superclass referencing to the array?

```
private var backgroundGrid = []; //the array which the grids are stored in, in the main class.



public class Grid extends MovieClip
{

    protected var node :PathfindNode; //the variable I wish to access, from an instance of subclass.

    public function Grid(){
        node = new PathfindNode();
    }


}



public class GrassTile1 extends Grid { //every subclass of Grid will extends Grid


    public function GrassTile1() {
        // constructor code
    }
}

function getBackgroundGrid(i:int,j:int):Grid{ //in the main class
        return Grid(backgroundGrid[i][j]); // this line gives me an error 
    }
```

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert GrassTile1@2905d5f1 to Grid.

I've tried accessing backgroundGrid[i][j].node and other ways to work around that I could think of and failed. Any Idea?

Comment: I set up a simple .fla and set up the file as I am assuming you did based on what you have said, and I got no error.

Comment: See my updated answer. Would be good if you threw a trace in the constructors to ensure what you expect is happening is actually happening. I didn't need to call super, and it works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
return backgroundGrid[i][j] as Grid;
```

Personally, `Grid` seems like a bad class name to use. I think `Tile` makes more sense, as that `GrassTile1` is not a grid as I logically understand a grid. A grid might contain a collection of tiles, so doesn't sound logical to use that as a class name for tiles.

Also, where is the line where you actually call the getBackgroundGrid method ? You should try casting there, as opposed to in that method. I believe that will solve the problem.

I can't verify the line throwing the error, so we are assuming that it's the return statement. But, it could be on the other side where you are calling getBackgroundGrid.

UPDATE : I have tried a .fla using what you are describing and it works just fine, I get no error. Which is why I'm thinking we are missing something here and maybe the definition of the class is not being used. Can you put a trace in your constructors to verify what you expect is actually happening ?

Comment: I've tried that, but it does not solve the issue. By the way,  isnt return Grid(backgroundGrid[i][j]) and return backgroundGrid[i][j] as Grid the same thing? Thanks for trying to help. I've resolve this issue by ensuring all subclasses calls the super() in the constructor, and putting the subclasses and superclass in the same file.

Comment: You don't show us what is in that array with real code and you are just giving us snippets here so I fear there are things we cannot evaluate here. Is there an instance in the library that is named GrassTile1 ? If so, then it will autocreate a class. And if your class is not implemented correctly, that could result in it not extending Grid as you expect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268329/as3-cast-or-as - I tend to use `as`, was just curious if it made a difference. There shouldn't be a difference in terms of what we are trying to achieve.

Comment: If it's a library symbol, then you need to set Grid as the base class in the properties panel. I think that might be the core issue here. Not sure how it handles the situation where your .as defined class differs in your definition from that auto-created definition.

Comment: Also, where is the line where you actually call the getBackgroundGrid method ? You should try casting there, as opposed to in that method. I believe that is the problem.