# When to use either type casting or the "as" operator in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, casting

I have seen quite a bunch of codes casting objects from one type to another type, using what I call the "standard" casting, like this:

```
var myDO:DisplayObject = loader.content;
var myCastedMC:MovieClip = MovieClip(myDO);
```

However the `as` operator seems to work the same way, because when I traced both objects I get the same value:

```
var myAsMC:MovieClip = myDO as MovieClip;
trace(myAsMC,myCastedMC); //both outputs read [object MainTimeline]
```

So, what is the difference between these two? When do yo use the `as` operator and when do you use the "standard" casting?

Comment: [Possible Duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268329/as3-cast-or-as)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cast only when you are certain the cast will succeed. If casting fails a runtime error is thrown.
You use 'as' to produce a soft cast that will never throw an error. In that case either the cast succeed or the default value of the datatype is returned (for most object that is null).
Both casts are meant to be used in very different situations but since they are misunderstood often you will see 'as' being used when the coder really meant a direct cast. 
If following a cast the coder will not check or need to check if the cast has succeeded then it should have used a direct cast. If following a cast the coder needs to check if the cast has succeeded, he should use 'as'.

It should be explained why hitman answer is not correct. The provided code assume success:

```
(getChildAt(i) as TextField).text=i.toString();
```

Meaning coder knows the display list only contains TextField object (or else an error will occur). In that case a direct cast is recommended:

```
TextField(getChildAt(i)).text = i.toString();
```

If the display list contains other object types then 'as' can be used:

```
var field:TextField = getChildAt(i) as TextField;
if(field)//if null then getChildAt(i) is not a TextField
{
    //field exist so cast succeeded
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question!

on of their differences is that casting is conversion at compile and "as" is converting at runtime.and one of others is that you can only convert subclasses to superclasses.but "as" converts anything.

let's have an example:

let's say we have a lot of textfields on stage and we don't have them in variables or an array.and we want to change their text by a loop:

```
for(var i:uint=0;i<numChildren;i++){
    var t:TextField=getChildAt(i)
    t.text=i.toString();

}
```

probably you see an error because `getChildAt`returns displayObject and displayObject doesn't have `text` property!

so you must use `as` here:

```
for(var i:uint=0;i<numChildren;i++){

    (getChildAt(i) as TextField).text=i.toString();

}
```

H☻pes this helps!

Comment: That is exactly the opposite of what 'as' is meant for. You do not check if the cast succeed so a direct cast should be used.