# Type coercion in AS3 Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5, type-coercion

I am making a simple jumper game in AS3 in Flash, and at this moment everything works but I get this note:

Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert 2 to flash.display.Scene.
    at scratch_theGame_kat_fla::MainTimeline/startkeyPressed()

I understand there must be a type of an instance that is incorrect when this note appears, but as I search around in my code to find the perpetrator, I realized the "2" that it must be referring to is this:

```
function startkeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode,Keyboard.ENTER)
    {
        trace("new player");
        startGame = true;
        gotoAndPlay(( 1, Scene (2)));
    }
};
```

This part of the code is what makes it go (when ENTER is pressed) from scene 1 to scene 2, where the actual game begins. Does anyone have any idea what I should change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line makes **absolutely** no sense in terms of AS3 logic:

```
gotoAndPlay(( 1, Scene (2)));
```

If you look into "**Example**" section of the [official **gotoAndPlay(...)** help](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndPlay()), there are two possible uses of this method:

1. You pass a single "frame" argument: it is either a 1-based **int** frame index, or it is a **String** label of the desired frame.
2. Two arguments where the second one is the **String** name of a **Scene** that is a portion of the main timeline, and the first is, again, the frame index or frame label inside the said **Scene**.

Now let's decipher what you have there. You are passing as **gotoAndPlay(...)** arguments. Feel the difference:

```
// Your version: one argument grouped with additional brackets.
gotoAndPlay(( 1, Scene (2)));

// Alternate version: no additional brackets, two arguments.
gotoAndPlay(1, Scene (2));
```

Then, what is **Scene (2)** expression, you might probably ask? It is called **typecasting**, an operation where you:

1. Explicitly state the exact class of something you are working with, because there are moments where compiler does not know exactly, like what is the exact class of **Event.target** object. There's a nice example, well explained: [AS3: cast or "as"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14268329/4687633)
2. You want to explicitly convert data from one type to another (the said *type coercion*), mostly used between **int** or **Number** and **String** types.

Lets see:

```
function onEvent(e:Event):void
{
    // Explicit typecasting.
    MovieClip(e.target).nextFrame();

    // Explicit typecasting through "as" operator.
    var aFrame:int = (e.target as MovieClip).currentFrame;

    // Explicit type conversion.
    trace("The current frame is", String(aFrame));
```

So, you are trying to convince Flash Player that integer value **2** is somehow a **Scene** object, but there's no way it is, hence the exception thrown by the **Flash Player** because it does not understand what do you want it to do.

The correct notation of what you are trying to achieve (moving the playhead to the second **Scene**) would be probably:

```
gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene2");
```

The "**Scene2**" argument is a string literal that should represent the **exact** name of that second scene of yours, I couldn't know what it is but it should probably be named "**Scene2**" or "**Scene 2**" by default.